# react native ugprade to 0.63 upgrade to .jar binary

Tags: react-native

I am upgrading to RN 0.63.2 and one of the files changed is the grade-wrapper.jar, am I supposed to download this file and overwrite the current one?  It isn't a viewable file so I am not sure what else to do.  Or is just a diff that gets auto-generated?

Comment: If it helps, I downloaded and overwrote the file when I upgraded a few weeks back.

Comment: thanks but im kinda keen to hear a more explanation answer, overwriting bitcode is just a little scary haha